# Amino acids in human cancer cells expose dextrorotation?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, amino-acids, chirality

I would like to know if the amino acids in the human cancer cells are dextrorotatory or levorotatory.
I mean the majority of them.
They expose levorotation just like the amino acids in the normal cells or they are different?

I mean in general. Maybe some particular types of cancer are significantly different from the rest.

I'll try to make the question more on-topic: The amino acids in cancer cells are also levorotatory, just like the amino acids in the normal cells?

This book: [Breaking the Cancer Code: A Revolutionary Approach to Reversing Cancer](https://books.google.es/books?id=OXZ-AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=cancer%20cells%20grow%20in%20dextrorotation&source=bl&ots=Fgdj3p3wBQ&sig=HvTR7y9CrwNg2zaIjqfSzuRRF7w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidhofKuc_MAhUKvRoKHUL9ACAQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=cancer%20cells%20grow%20in%20dextrorotation&f=false) says "We know that tumor cells grow in dextrorotation" - so I wonder where the author(s) know that from. They must be speaking about amino acids inside tumor cells, when they say "tumor cells"

Comment: what makes you think there is more R in tumors? Is this a wild guess? If yes, this question is off topic

Comment: What brings you to this conclusion? Where should this amino acids come from? Can you please add some references about it?

Comment: No idea where they can come from, but I remember reading this in a science magazine a long time ago. How can I make the question more on topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a 30 second look at the book you mentioned. The authors just made this up, just like 95% of the book.

The authors are not wrong, they didn't want to write something useful and made a mistake, they're just bullshitting: They're making stuff up, letting it sound a tiny bit scientific and try to sell a lot of books.

If you want to know more about something, usually Wikipedia is a good place to start, and if you're not sure how to distinguish between science and pseudoscience it might be a good idea to read a bit about recognizing pseudoscience.

Now to answer your question: cancer cells are almost the same as normal cells, and they contain mostly levorotatory amino acids. The main difference between a cancer cell and a normal cell is that the cancer cell has one or more mutations that cause it to divide a lot more than normal cells. The DNA, proteins and small molecules in the cells are mostly the same as in normal cells, that's why it's so hard to specifically kill cancer cells.

Comment: I can't vote yet, but thanks for the answer. I think it's much better to talk about pseudoscience and debunk it's myths than to pretend it doesn't exist. Therefore such questions and answers are highly valuable. Just my 2 cents.